# Delete data from calendar cell and database on button click in calendar cell

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, c#-4.0, calendar

[image]

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Double;
lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlanchedAlmond;
lbl.Text = eventname + "<br/>" + dt + "--" + dt1;
e.Cell.Controls.Add(lbl);

btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnCross_Click);
e.Cell.Controls.Add(btn);

public void btnCross_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = ((Button)sender).ID;
}
```

My database fields are id, name , eventstartdate , eventenddate

**How should i accomplish this** my calendar control is in a UpdatePanel that is why this btnCross_Click is not firing

Comment: Please, in the future, take some time to format the code. You have a preview just underneath the question text. It's a small change that makes it much easier for readers of your question to follow the code.

Comment: Would you mind telling us what `e` is? Is it an `asp:Table` perhaps?

Comment: alright i am sorry will take care next time

Comment: this code is under the Day_Render event of the Asp.net Calender
protected void myCal_DayRender1(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)

Comment: Okay. You *do* build the same control structure on each postback, correct? Because if you don't, the button click event will not fire.

Comment: The problem is that the calender control is in an Updatepanel and this is the issue the dynamically created button click is not firing...

Comment: I see. Do you get any error when doing the postback? If you have firefox with firebug for instance an error will pop up in the Console tab. (pressing F12 in most browsers will show a similar debug window)

Comment: when i debug it does not come to the btn_Click even if i press the button

Comment: No, you established that. What I was asking is if you got any error in the console output when you clicked the button.

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Comment: Your creating button and click event binding code executed too late in page lifecycle. Consider to save created dynamic buttons ids in some perisitent storage like ViewState and re-create they not later than Page_Load method

Comment: i want to bind this data to a calender is the solution feasable as u suggested ?

Comment: You might have better luck in subclassing the Calendar control, or using an existing. There's an article on CodeProject named [DataCalendar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5347/DataCalendar) that might get you started. Note that that control also lacks the possibility of adding buttons in the dayrender function..

Answer (score 1):

The idea of code below is to create all required controls in Page_Load method and move them further in appropriate container.

```
<asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="Calendar1" Width="800px" Height="700px" BackColor="White"
    BorderColor="Black" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="10pt"
    ForeColor="Black" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" TitleFormat="Month" ShowGridLines="true" >
    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" ForeColor="#333333"
        Height="10pt" />
    <DayStyle Width="14%" />
    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White" />
    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#CC3333" ForeColor="White" />
    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
        ForeColor="#333333" Width="1%" />
    <TitleStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="13pt" ForeColor="White"
        Height="14pt" />
    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
</asp:Calendar>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code-behind:

```
private Dictionary<DateTime, List<Control>> DayControls = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<Control>>();

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar1.DayRender += new DayRenderEventHandler(Calendar1_DayRender);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if(Calendar1.VisibleDate == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
        }
    }
    FillDayControls(Calendar1.VisibleDate);
}

void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (!DayControls.ContainsKey(e.Day.Date)) return;

    foreach (var control in DayControls[e.Day.Date])
    {
        control.Parent.Controls.Remove(control);

        e.Cell.Controls.Add(control);

        if (control is Button)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(control.UniqueID);
        }
    }
}

private void FillDayControls(DateTime dateTime)
{
    var firstMonthDate = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);

    var calendarFirstWeekDay = Calendar1.FirstDayOfWeek == FirstDayOfWeek.Default
                                ? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
                                : (DayOfWeek) (int) Calendar1.FirstDayOfWeek;

    var currentDate = firstMonthDate.DayOfWeek == calendarFirstWeekDay ? firstMonthDate.AddDays(-7) : firstMonthDate.AddDays((int)firstMonthDate.DayOfWeek * -1);
    var lastDate = currentDate.AddDays(41);

    do
    {
        var events = GetCalendarEvents(currentDate);
        if (events.Count > 0)
        {
            DayControls.Add(currentDate, new List<Control>());
        }

        foreach (var calendarEvent in events)
        {
            var lbl = new Label
                            {
                                BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black,
                                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Double,
                                BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlanchedAlmond,
                                Text = string.Format("{0}<br />{1:hh:mm:ss tt} -- {2:hh:mm:ss tt}", calendarEvent.Title, calendarEvent.Start, calendarEvent.End)
                            };
            DayControls[currentDate].Add(lbl);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lbl);

            var btn = new Button
                            {
                                Text = "x",
                                ID = "DeleteEvent_" + calendarEvent.Id,
                                CommandName = "DeleteEvent",
                                CommandArgument = calendarEvent.Id
                            };

            DayControls[currentDate].Add(btn);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

        }

        currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
    } while (currentDate <= lastDate);
}

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var eventId = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
}

private List<CalendarEvent> GetCalendarEvents(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return new List<CalendarEvent>{
                    new CalendarEvent
                    {
                        Id = string.Format("{0:MMMddyyyy}Event" ,dateTime),
                        Start = dateTime.Date.AddHours(10),
                        End = dateTime.Date.AddHours(12),
                        Title = string.Format("{0:dd/MM} meeting", dateTime)
                    }};
}
```

CalendarEvent class stub:

```
public class CalendarEvent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```